# Restsharp request with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, restsharp

As far as I understood....
RestSharp serializer's output is always a String. String is defined by .Net as collection of characters using UTF-16. So there is no way to modify the encoding of the request, so I can change it, the header will be changed, the XML header will be UTF-8 for example, but the encoding of the request will be always a String so it will be UTF-16.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8

```cs
using System;namespace RestSharp.Serializers
{
    public interface ISerializer
    {
        string ContentType { get; set; }        
        string Serialize(object obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: A string is a string is a string. The encoding and decoding of text in a transport protocol is responsibility of the library/classes that deals with the finer details of said transport protocol. RestSharp should normally deal with this just fine. Now, in what context exactly does make RestSharp problems with you? **Add** a [mcve] to your question that demonstrates your actual problem together with a REST response that is necessary to (re)produce the problem you encounter.

Comment: Also, have you checked the documentation (or IntelliSense, or the RestSharp source code on Github) whether and how the RestClient or RestRequest classes would allow you to specify a particular encoding explicitely in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I found the solution. Client.Encoding property sets the encoding, checking the RestSharp code it used to set  the bytes in the request.